# How can the homogeneous system $AX=0$ have infinitely many solutions if $|A|=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in M_{nxn}$ be a matrix and $|A|$ be the determinant of $A$.
Why does the homogeneous system $$AX=0$$ have infinitely many solutions when $|A| = 0$?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ has zero determinant, it is not invertible. That means there is a nonzero $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $Ax = 0$. Then by linearity of $A$, every scalar multiple of $x$ is mapped to zero by $A$. This yields an infinite number of solutions.